# How to set option for compiler in premake4?

Tags: premake

How can I set option that is available for particular compiler in premake4?

For instance only in Visual Studio set "Whole Program Optimization"?
This option is not available in GCC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [the development version of Premake](https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-dev), you can set [the link-time optimization flag](https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-dev/wiki/flags):

```
flags { "LinkTimeOptimization" }
```

If you are using [the stable version](https://bitbucket.org/premake/premake-stable), you can get the same effect by setting the command line flag explicitly for Visual Studio:

```
configuration "vs*"
    buildoptions { "/GL" }
```